# Shielded Cables in Redundant Links

Tags: cables, shield

In the following diagram from a Redundant Emergency Stop (p.356 [ref](https://library.e.abb.com/public/1fb150c613d5457d98a379a3ce8b6360/EN_ACS580-01_HW_B_A5_screen.pdf)), there are two pairs of shielded cable.

At the (1) end, the two individual shields are grounded. 
At the (3) end, after the Z symbol, appear a single overall shield grounded to the (1) end (not the (3) end), and do not show anything about the individual shields.

Note that being a redundant loop having a single cable with two pairs is not very plausible. These should be two separate pairs (at least not in a same cable)...

Should I use a double shielded twisted pair with overall shield, or two single shielded twisted pairs? In the first case, which is the sense of having a redundant link in a same cable?

[image]

Comment: I believe its split that way because if any of the cables gets interrupted, the connection gets opened. If you have the same pair on the same cable, the connection still passes through the other cable.

Comment: Agreed. But then, what is that overall shield symbol? If those pairs are in a single cable, why to bother about redundancy at all?

Comment: it has to make sure that the connection is opened/broken when you want it to be. I believe the Z represents a twisted pair

Comment: If Z represents twisted pair this has much more sense. Still the overall shield is unclear for me.

Comment: I read this as *If there is any common shield anywhere, it must be connected to a **seperate** shield wire and connected to the star ground.* This is stated to avoid people connecting the two shields at a second point near (3).